# A problem involving complex polynomials

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, contest-math

This question came up in the partial solution to an olympiad problem, in an attempt to complete the proof

Suppose $P(a,b)$ is a complex polynomial satisfying

$$P(a,b)= 0 \implies a^2 + b^2 = 0$$

Is it necessarily the case that

$$P(a,b) = k(a+ ib)^m(a-ib)^n$$?

My approach was to define the complex polynomial of one argument,

$$f_c(a) = P(a,c)$$

And to note that the roots of $f$ satisfy

$$ a = \pm ic $$

So that $f_c$ can be factorised as

$$ f_c(a) = k(a+ic)^m(a-ic)^n $$

And so for any $c'$ we also have

$$f_{c'}(a) = k'(a+ic')^{m'}(a-ic')^{n'} $$

And then I want to somehow use that $f_c$ and $f_{c}'$ must be connected by a continuous function, and we can "bring" $c$ and $c'$ as close to each other as we like, so that eventually the exponents and coefficient are forced to be the same. To try and make this more precise, we can take $\max\{m+n,m'+n'\}-1$ derivatives of both $f_c$ and $f_{c'}.$ W.l.o.g we can assume that the max of these is $m+n$. Then after taking $m+n-1$ derivatives, assuming $m+n>m'+n'$ we are left with a linear polynomial, $f^{(m+n-1)}_c$ and a constant polynomial $f^{(m+n-1)}_{c'}$. And it seems reasonable that a continuous complex function $g$ of two variables satisfying

$$\forall{\epsilon > 0}\forall_{c}\exists_{c',|c-c'|<\epsilon} \\ [g(z,c) \mbox{ is linear and non constant } \land g(z,c') \mbox{ is constant}] $$

Does not exist, but I am struggling to make this intuition precise, and even if it were made precise, it only allows one to conclude that $m+n= m'+n'$, and I am not sure how this would even help. Any insight into the problem, or highlighting of errors in my thinking so far would be appreciated. Keep in mind that my background in complex analysis is not fantastic, so an elegant proof using complicated theorems may go over my head

Comment: just out of my curiosity , from which olympiad is this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it is to make the change of variables $c=a+ib, d=a-ib$ and consider $Q(c,d)=P(\frac{c+d}{2}, \frac{c-d}{2i})=P(a,b)$ which now has the property that $Q(c,d)=0$ implies $cd=0$. We will prove that $Q=kc^md^n$ which then gives the required result by substituting back to $a,b$

We will prove below that if $Q$ nonconstant either $c | Q$ or $d |Q$. After this, the result follows by induction on the degree of $Q$ since in degree $1$, $c | Q$ or $d |Q$ implies $Q=kc$ or $Q=kd$ and if $Q$ has degree $N \ge 2$ and say wlog $c | Q$ considering $Q_1=Q/c$ we have that $Q_1$ has degree $N-1 \ge 1$ and satisfies the same property since $Q_1(c,d)=0$ implies $Q(c,d)=0$ so by the induction hypothesis it is $kc^md^n, m+n=N-1$ and then $Q=kc^{m+1}d^n$ and we are done.

Let $Q$ has degree $N \ge 1$ and let's assume that the highest degree of $c$ is $M \ge 1$ since if $Q$ is a polynomial only in $d$ the required result is obvious (as then $Q(c,d)=Q(1,d)$ it folows that $Q$ has only zero as root in $d$ so it is $kd^N$)

Assume now by contradiction that neither $c$ nor $d$ divides $Q$ and let's write $Q(c,d)=k+cR(c)+dR_1(d)+Q_2(c,d)$ where $cd | Q_2$ and either $R,R_1$ are both non zero or $k \ne 0$ (or of course any combination of such) as otherwise either $c |Q$ or $d |Q$.

Then there is a monomial $S$ of minimal degree that doesn't divide by $c$ - either the free term $k$ if that is non zero, or the smallest degree term of $dR_1(d)$ since if $k=0$ that must be non zero. But now let's order the monomials in $c$ of degree $M$ in lexicographic order, so the highest is $\alpha c^Md^{M_1}, M+M_1 \le N$ and let's write $Q=S+\alpha c^Md^{M_1}+Q_3$

We notice that for large enough $q$ then $Q(c^q,c)$, which is a polynomial in $c$, has only one term of the highest degree in $c$, namely $\alpha c^{Mq+M_1}$ (as $Mq$ dominates all the terms that come from monomials in $Q$ which have degree in $c$ at most $M-1$ for $q$ large enough as those have degrees at most $(M-1)q+N$ in $Q(c^q,c)$, as well as the ones coming from the monomials in $c$ of degree $M$ by our choice)

Also, $Q(c^q,c)$ has a non-zero lowest degree monomial $S(c)$ again by our choices so we get that for large enough $q$, $Q(c^q,c)=\beta c^{m_0}+ Q_4(c)+\alpha c^{Mq+M_1} $ where the monomials in $Q_4$ (if any) have degrees strictly greater than $m_0$ and strictly less than $Mq+M_1$; but such a polynomial clearly has a non zero root $c_0$ so $Q$ has the root $(c_0^q,c_0)$ contradicting the hypothesis on the roots of $Q$. Done!